# Jquery 1.8.3 not simultaneously working for two plugins

Tags: jquery, html

So I have two Plugins running on my html website , one is a music player and the other is the lightbox ,

[Link here](http://aceaccentuating.com/trial/)

Both use Jquery 1.8.3

Now if included in line 203 the Lightbox works and the Music player doesnt .

If included on line 65 the Music player works and the Ligtbox Doesn't .

I dont know why this is happening or how to solve it , i'm still learning so help would be much appreciated !

The Link has Jquery included on the 65th line so currently the music player works

Comment: Please provide relevant lines of code not simply a link.

Comment: the code is slightly long thats why i didnt include it

Comment: Put the code up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: it contains lots of images and other files which need to be included apart from  jquery

Comment: Your lightbox js is throwing a 404:  ../js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js

Comment: now if you check [link](http://aceaccentuating.com/trial/light.html) here the lightbox works and the music player doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on this page: http://aceaccentuating.com/trial/light.html your jquery include is too low down - this means that anything using jquery above where you include the library will not work.

on this page: http://aceaccentuating.com/trial/ you have some sort of type error on line 267 -

```
var $container  = $('.am-container'),
```

gives the following error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

which means it has jquery has been undefined by this point in one of your many files - see this: [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Comment: bows down ! you have saved me alot of time and effort ! all i did was pull up the lightbox code ! and everything works ! thank you for your time and patience !