# jQuery snippet in custom WordPress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll

I've found a [jQuery scroll trick](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/) that I would like to use in my custom WordPress theme. The problem I have is that the function given to `.scroll()` is never executed.

For the purpose of debugging, I have reduced the script to the following:

```
(function () {
  alert("foo");
  $(window).scroll(function (evt) {
    alert("bar");
  });
})();
```

I have placed the js in `mytheme.js` and added the following to `functions.php`:

```
function mytheme_enq_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script('mytheme', get_template_directory_uri().'/mytheme.js',
    array('jquery'), '0.1', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enq_script');
```

The PHP must be correct, because the script is loaded and the "foo" alert appears, but the "bar" alert does not. What's wrong with my minimal jQuery code?

Comment: Open up developer tools, firebug or just plain view source and see if that js file is linked.

Comment: The js is linked indeed: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/.../wp-content/themes/mytheme/mytheme.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>`

Comment: In fact, I experiment by adding `alert("foo");` just before `$(window).scroll(...` and `alert("bar");` as first statement in the scroll handler. The first alert appears when page loads, the second one never appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the web console, skimmed through [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function) and changed the js to the following:

```
(function ($) {
  alert("foo");
  $(window).scroll(function (evt) {
    alert("bar");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Now it loads as expected.