# Calling a (document).resize and (document).ready

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to call an equal height function using `$(document).ready`, though I had to call it like this, because I was getting a Type Error.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(".cols").equalHeights();
});
```

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cols").equalHeights();
});
```

This works great, but I would also like the plugin to run when the page is resized, (so it will adjust to the content overflow). Below is the resize call, how can  I combine it with the document ready call?

```
$(".cols").resize(function(){
    $(".cols").equalHeights();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cols = $(".cols");

        cols.resize(function(){
            cols.equalHeights();
        });

        cols.trigger('resize');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, though the three selectors aren't all necessary. One would be sufficient.

Comment: Ah ok, ye i'm pretty new to jQuery, just was a bit unsure of the syntax

Comment: You can chain the `trigger` call as well ;)

Comment: @Joe_Maker I recommend you to check out [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I've never really liked chaining personally.

Comment: @Lloyd It falls into the principles of DRY

Comment: I'm getting a Type Error on equalHeights again.

Comment: Are you sure equalHeights exists?

Comment: Yes, i'm linking to it in the head after the jQuery library. it was working before with just:

jQuery(function($) {
$(".cols").equalHeights();
});

But after combining it with the resize, it has returned the Type Error

Comment: You shouldn't need to use both `jQuery` AND `$` unless you're altering the meaning of `$` later. It's also global so you shouldn't need to pass it through to the function :/

Comment: Hmm that was the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function
I'll try to figure it out

Comment: @Joe_Maker Yes because `$` was not available, probably through `noConflict()`. They simply pass through `jQuery` for use as `$`, I've edited my code to show something similar.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I understand why it wasn't working now.

Comment: @Joe_Maker, why don't you post your code as a new answer, instead of editing this one?

Answer (score 1):

This code calls the jquery equalHeights plugin found here: http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.UcOQiPm1HOU

---

It now works when the window is resized.

---

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var cols = $(".cols");
       cols.resize(function () {
           cols.equalHeights();
        });
        cols.trigger('resize');
    });
      $(window).resize(function(){
            $(".cols").css("height","auto").equalHeights(); // maybe reset the height?
      }).resize() // trigger a resize to start off everything.
})(jQuery);
```