# Dollar sign ("$") is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unsure of why I'm getting this error, but for some reason jQuery's `$` is not being recognised?

```
jQuery(window).load(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /* Preloader */
    $(".status").fadeOut();
    $(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

}); /* END WIDNOW LOAD */
```

NOTE: changing `$` to `jQuery` fixes the issue (so I'm sure jQuery is referenced correctly, am using version 2.1.4), but I would like to continue using `$` for semantics.

Comment: Your parameter is a `$`

Comment: Rename your parameter, problem solved. Happy life carries on.

Comment: `$` is the event. You could pass it to ready method but not load method. This would be for example to handle `$` in wordpress `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`

Comment: This is a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function I believe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are overriding the `$` variable inside your function, because you have an argument with the same name.

Remove the `$` argument and `$` will again refer to the global scoped one, equal to `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    'use strict';

    /* Preloader */
    $(".status").fadeOut();
    $(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

}); /* END WIDNOW LOAD */
```

You *can* use a parameter for the handler function passed into `load`. I suggest the same as [Anik Islam Abhi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817365/419956): use another name for the argument. For example `e` or `eventArgs`.

Note that you (or others landing here) might actually be trying to use a pattern that makes sure `jQuery` is available as `$` inside certain scope (e.g. because there may be a conflict with another library also declaring `$` in global scope). If that's the case, I suggest something along these lines:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        'use strict';

        /* Preloader */
        $(".status").fadeOut();
        $(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

    }); /* END WIDNOW LOAD */
}(jQuery));
```

This will wrap all your code inside a function which is executed immediately with `jQuery` passed in as an argument. Because `$` is the name of the argument of that function, you'll know for sure that `$` is equal to the global `jQuery` within that function's scope.

Comment: $ could refers to something else than jQuery

Comment: @A.Wolff Good point. Could be OP or others are looking for a pattern to *make sure* that `$` refers to `jQuery`, I've added a footnote / second part with some code to handle that case.

Comment: Kudos for pointing out the IIFE wrapper, which binds `jQuery` to `$` as the function begins to execute.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding event parameter with $

Try like this

```
jQuery(window).load(function (e) {
    'use strict';

    /* Preloader */
    $(".status").fadeOut();
    $(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

}); /* END WIDNOW LOAD */
```

Comment: `$` could refers to something else than jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanted something like that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /* Preloader */
    $(".status").fadeOut();
    $(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

}); /* END WIDNOW LOAD */
```

Comment: Ya, i think it is what OP is looking for, handling $ to refers to jQuery inside ready handler

Answer (score 1):

```
$ = jQuery;
```

can work too. Not the best way though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Leave it at the top of the js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).