# TypeError: $(...).predictiveSearch is not a function

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to use a plugin named `predictiveSearch` for the type-ahead functionality, but I get the error:

> TypeError: $(...).predictiveSearch is not a function

I tried re-ordering the loading of scripts but still not working. Can someone please help. Here is the code.

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../js/predictiveSearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.predictive-search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search"  method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control predictive-search" autocomplete="off" data-module="predictive-search" data-url="../json/predictiveSearchResults.json">
       <!-- form elements... -->
    </form>
</body>
```

predictiveSearch.js contains the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-module="predictive-search"]').predictiveSearch();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery.noconflict(); helped resolving the error

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the JS file containing the plugin *before* the JS file that initialises the plugin. Change your `<script>` elements to this order:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../js/jquery.predictive-search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/predictiveSearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I did try that, but the issue still remains same.

Comment: In which case the `jquery.predictive-search.js` file is not being loaded correctly. Ensure the path to it is correct, and that there are no errors in the console.

Comment: using jquery.noconflict(); helped resolving the error. Thank you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function