# Hide or show input field based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this script which works perfectly fine on fiddle, but not working on my website.

http://jsfiddle.net/P2Ab2/30/

Code on site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".hiddenInput").hide();
$(".showHideCheck").on("change", function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $input = $this.parent().find(".hiddenInput");
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
        $input.slideDown();
    } else {
        $input.slideUp();
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox1" id="chkBox1" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
        <br/><div class="hiddenInput"> Enter
        <input type="text" name="txtBox1"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="chkBox2" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
        <br/><div class="hiddenInput">Enter
        <input type="text" name="txtBox2"/></div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are getting in js console ?

Comment: "Not working" is no a description of a problem. Please read this: [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the elements before they are even loaded in the page. So, there are two simpler ways to solve your problem.

**First**

You can use the [jQuery's document ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { // encapsulate your code into a function and pass it to jQuery
  $(".hiddenInput").hide();
  $(".showHideCheck").on("change", function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $input = $this.parent().find(".hiddenInput");
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
        $input.slideDown();
    } else {
        $input.slideUp();
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox1" id="chkBox1" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
        <br/><div class="hiddenInput"> Enter
        <input type="text" name="txtBox1"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="chkBox2" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
        <br/><div class="hiddenInput">Enter
        <input type="text" name="txtBox2"/></div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second**

You can mantain your code intact, but put the script before the end of the body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox1" id="chkBox1" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
        <br/><div class="hiddenInput"> Enter
        <input type="text" name="txtBox1"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="chkBox2" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
        <br/><div class="hiddenInput">Enter
        <input type="text" name="txtBox2"/></div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".hiddenInput").hide();
$(".showHideCheck").on("change", function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $input = $this.parent().find(".hiddenInput");
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
        $input.slideDown();
    } else {
        $input.slideUp();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works both ways.

Comment: @MohitChandak So, please, click in the arrow to upvote my answer, and then in the V to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing

```
$(".hiddenInput").hide();
```

on the header, before the element is loaded. Try putting your script after the elements on body:

```
...
    <div class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="chkBox2" class="showHideCheck" />Click me to show the text box
    <br/><div class="hiddenInput">Enter
    <input type="text" name="txtBox2"/></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".hiddenInput").hide();
    $(".showHideCheck").on("change", function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $input = $this.parent().find(".hiddenInput");
        if($this.is(":checked")) {
            $input.slideDown();
        } else {
            $input.slideUp();
        }
    });
</script>
```

OR setup a function to execute on load event:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        $(".hiddenInput").hide();
        $(".showHideCheck").on("change", function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $input = $this.parent().find(".hiddenInput");
            if($this.is(":checked")) {
                $input.slideDown();
            } else {
                $input.slideUp();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="start()>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: How do i do that? function to execute on load event?

Comment: which is made with pure javascript. If you want a JQuery solution, @Buzinas answer is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".hiddenInput").hide();
        $(".showHideCheck").on("change", function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $input = $this.parent().find(".hiddenInput");
            if($this.is(":checked")) {
               $input.slideDown();
           } else {
              $input.slideUp();
           }
       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [jQuery JavaScript not working on Wordpress, confused about no-conflict mode syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086140/jquery-javascript-not-working-on-wordpress-confused-about-no-conflict-mode-synt/32086637#32086637) if your website happens to be a wordpress site.

If wordpress, try:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

   // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
   // console.log($);
   // put code here

   });
```

if you are not using wordpress, try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // put code here
});
```