# responsive grid in pixit template

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I am having a problem in placing responsive grid in PIXIT template. PIXIT template is fully responsive and made up on bootstrap 3.0.

I have downloaded this template from here [pixit](http://themeforest.net/item/pixit-admin-frontend-template/7528815)

I have downloaded FOOTABLE responsive grid , it worked perfectly in test page but when I tried to place it in the project (pixit template) it looses it responsiveness...

Can any body share his/her experience to how to use asp grid with responsive features?

During search I came across with the terminology "Bootstrap 3 Responsive Grid Photoshop Templates (PSD)". Can I use this template in VS 2012?

Comment: During search i came across with the following link to answer the smilar question.http://stackoverflow.com/users/569077/doonot. however i am not been able to solve mine problem...if Mr Doonot can comment...

Answer (score 0):

i googled a bit and followed the following link [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

i just changed my jquery function from

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').footable({

            breakpoints: {
                phone: 480,
                tablet: 1024
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
         $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').footable({
            breakpoints: {
                phone: 480,
                tablet: 1024
            }
        });
     });        
</script>
```

it worked like a champ.