# jQuery div rotator working on Fiddle but not WordPress website. Tried 3 things

Tags: jquery, wordpress, rotation

I'm using a jQuery div rotator like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/kDSqB which is working very nicely in the Fiddle. When I move the same code over to my WordPress website, it doesn't work.

I tried adding jQuery no conflict, adding a DOM document ready, and changing the $(document.body) to the name of the parent div. None of these worked.

I also tried moving all of the pertaining jQuery inline to the part of the page where the code would appear, but still the div does not rotate. What should I do?

Below is all the code for this on my WordPress website:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js">

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function(){

var $cog = $('#cog'),
$body = $(document.body),
bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
$cog.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
});
});
});
});
</script>
<div class="cogclass"><div id="cog"></div></div>
```

Comment: what error you from the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=] and Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fitVids is not a function, however that is one less than the number of errors that were on the page before I added the above code in. I don't know why that would happen.

Comment: Why are you defining your body like `$body = $(document.body)`? A simple `$body = $('body')` should do. If you are using jQuery, be consistent.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the $body. That didn't make the code work. I've also checked the jQuery noConflict in the Fiddle, and that part is not working in the fiddle. I've created a new one to show what I mean. Is there a problem with the way I'm doing it? http://jsfiddle.net/pcud2vyz/

Comment: I checked the errors in the browser console comparing the errors I had in there before I added the code and after. This is the error that was there after I added the code: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function (anonymous function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the console error and found this post: [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function). It turns out it may be a WordPress thing, and I have to put the code inside jQuery(document).ready(function($){ *code here* ;

So this code ended up working out:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var $cog = $('#cog'),
$body = $('body'),
bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
$cog.css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
});
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks to everyone who helped to find the answer!