# Want to fix Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my original Code

HTML -

```
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1">ONE</option>
    <option value="2">TWO</option>
    <option value="3">THREE</option>
    <option value="4">FOUR</option>
    <option value="5">FIVE</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
    <option value="1">ONE</option>
    <option value="2">TWO</option>
    <option value="3">THREE</option>
    <option value="4">FOUR</option>
    <option value="5">FIVE</option>
</select>
```

Javascript Code -

```
var sel2 = $('#sel2').html();
$('#sel1').change(function() {
    $('#sel2').html(sel2);
    $('#sel2 option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() <= $('#sel1').val()) $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This is the error when i embed this script in my site, please help me to fix this.

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Comment: include jquery file reference on your page

Comment: Have you imported jQuery?

Comment: Yes i used this JQUERY - <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js" type="text/javascript">

Comment: using any CMS or frame work...

Answer (score 1):

You should include JQuery reference in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Still not working, might be it conflicts with some other JS , i'm using WP platform

Comment: Ok, you can add JQuery reference from WP platform?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your order is not correct,Make sure you  put this code after you include `jquery`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
 //your code.
</script>
```

Comment: if you are using wp use `jQuery` in place of `$` and check.

Comment: if it work you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12343735/3143384 ans and can use `$` as well

Comment: Even if i use your Jquery, it stops my Slider to work , Here's my site URL - http://goo.gl/UY9DWH