# Insert Gridster into WordPress Backend

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, gridster

I have been trying to include Gridster into my WordPress Backend but it simply doesn't work. The frontend works fine, but I can't figure out why, because the files are actually in the following directories.

First way I tried it:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( "gridster-script", plugins_url( '/js/jquery.gridster.min.js', __FILE__  ), array('jquery') );
  wp_enqueue_script( "gridster-script-extra", plugins_url( '/js/jquery.gridster.with-extras.min.js', __FILE__ ), array('gridster-script'), true );
  wp_enqueue_script( "gridster-script-custom",  plugins_url( '/js/gridster.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
 }
```

Second one:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('gridster-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/jquery.gridster.min.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_enqueue_script('gridster-script-extra', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/jquery.gridster.with-extras.min.js', array('gridster-script') );
  wp_enqueue_script('gridster-script-custom', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/gridster.js', array('jquery') );
 }
```

Third and last one:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'gridster-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.gridster.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'gridster-script-extra', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.gridster.with-extras.min.js', array('gridster-script'), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'gridster-script-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gridster.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't randomly use plugin url functions, and need to choose the correct one for your use case. Assuming `__FILE__` is correctly referring to the main plugin file, you'll need to hook that function into the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action hook:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "gridster-script", plugins_url( 'js/jquery.gridster.min.js', __FILE__  ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( "gridster-script-extra", plugins_url( 'js/jquery.gridster.with-extras.min.js', __FILE__ ), array('gridster-script'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( "gridster-script-custom",  plugins_url( 'js/gridster.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. This post helped me too, because the file was included but was catching errors. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers the question, please select it as "correct."

Comment: Sorry forgot that :)