# jQuery in wordpress -- hiding objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to implement custom jQuery in one of the wordpress templates;

I added these lines to functions.php:

```
function my_custom_script() {
wp_enqueue_script('extra js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script');
```

Then I wanted to see if it works, so I simply added this to my extra.js file:

```
alert "Hello folks!";
```

And yup, alert appearing on the screen. Superb!

But if I want to add custom jQuery, let's say I got dic with id="firstBox":

```
$('#firstBox').click(function() {
    $('#firstBox').hide();
})
```

And nothing happens at all.

How to properly use jQuery in files like these?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function

Answer (score 0):

#### Making sure jQuery is loaded properly

Firstly, ensure that jQuery is being properly loaded at all. Let's deregister the `jquery` packaged and load from the CDN to ensure we have everything we need.

```
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
```

Now, enqueue your script with jquery as a dependency.

```
function my_extra_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'extra_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js', array('jquery') );
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_extra_enqueue");
```

#### No Conflicts

If you're still having issues at that point and seeing errors in your console like `$ is not a function` than you'll need to write your script with a `.noConflict()` variable. Sample script may be like:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('#firstBox').click(function() {
    $j('#firstBox').hide();
})
```

There are quite a few ways to go about setting up `.noConflict()` so do some reading to pick what works best for you. READ: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: You can confirm if this is your option by opening up your console and seeing if you're finding any reports like `$ is not defined`

Comment: Not the case. Still not running.
I'm getting: TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: are you seeing anything in your console log?

Comment: Yup. Just: "TypeError: $ is not a function" and the reference to extra.js

Comment: Yeah - your problem is definitely that jQuery isn't loaded - try the update above

Answer (score 0):

try to replace $ with jQuery

```
jQuery('#firstBox').click(function() {
    jQuery('#firstBox').hide();
})
```