# Random .attr('src', image) for an image(logo), why Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, random, attr

I've realized a random function to set different logo every time you refresh page:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/py3ttdc2/
```

But the browser console show this error:

```
(index):268 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    logoRandom  @   (index):268
    (anonymous function)    @   (index):265
```

UPDATE

sorry guys, but I wrote the code to show you only the string. This is the website: www.subbbilla.com and this is the jquery inside it `<script type='text/javascript' src='subbbilla.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/…;,` that was included yet.

Comment: You are using jQuery but you haven't loaded the jQuery library in your document.

Comment: Posting a jsFiddle link as code, because it tells you you have to write code if you post a jsFiddle link. You're diabolical...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: sorry guys,  but I wrote the code to show you only the string. This is the website: www.subbbilla.com and this is the jquery inside it 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://subbbilla.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>, that was included yet.

Answer (score 0):

Answered over and over.

jQuery isn't included, so `$` isn't found.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If it's _"answered over and over"_, mark it as a duplicate rather than answering _again_

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery as following :

[image]

[After adding jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/py3ttdc2/2/)

Or if you are working on your local machine  :

```
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```