# Calling jQuery in WordPress $ is not function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This was previously working fine for me but I think something changed how jQuery is being enqueued in WordPress.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#dialog-modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    bgiframe: true,
    title: 'Please Confirm',
    buttons: {
            "Ok!": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
            }
    }
}); 

$("[name='records']").on('change',function(e){
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
if(selectedValue==2) {

        $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
    }
});

});
```

My console displays :

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

I referenced this question:

[TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

But I still don't know how to wrap this correctly.

Comment: Have you enqueued the jQuery library in that page or header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the $ to jQuery like this:

```
/**
 *
 * Description
 *
 */

( function( window, $, undefined ) {

    'use strict';


    $( document ).ready( function(  ) {

        //what is this                                               
        $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            title: 'Please Confirm',
            buttons: {
                "Ok!": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        } ); 


        // what is this
        $("[name='records']").on('change',function(e){
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if(selectedValue==2) {

                $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
            }
        } ); 



    } ); //* end ready


} )( this, jQuery );
```

Comment: This doesn't show any console error, but it doesnt fire the modal anymore. I suspect that I was using a newer version of jquery prior and that wordpress's version (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4) is not working with this. Frustrating. I think I have to do some more digging. I will follow up.

Comment: You also have to register the main script, not just enqueue it, and then you call the dependency when you enqueue this script.

Comment: Thanks. Luckily I had a working backup. I was also missing jquery-ui.css, which was preventing the modal from appearing after the script was fixed. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try **jQuery** instead of **$**. Wordpress generally refences it as jQuery

As this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#dialog-modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    bgiframe: true,
    title: 'Please Confirm',
    buttons: {
            "Ok!": function() {
                    jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            }
    }
}); 

jQuery("[name='records']").on('change',function(e){
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
if(selectedValue==2) {

        jQuery('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
    }
});

});
```

I hope this works,,

Comment: I had tried that initially but as my comment above states I can't exactly say at the moment. I'm going to recheck my previous version to see if that's the issue now.