# Same java console errors even after rectification

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code worked flawlessly when added to master code which doesn't contain any jquery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            animationLoop: true,

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But when added to a template which already has jquery element, it gave following two errors in java console.

1.TypeError: $ is not a function

2.Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

Then I modified the code using '$.noConflict();' as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://project.dimpost.com/flexslider-carousel/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(window).load(function($) {
        jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            animationLoop: true,

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This again workes flawlessly when added to master code which doesn't contain any jquery script. But when added to the one having already running a jquery, it again shos the same two errors as described above:

1.TypeError: $ is not a function

2.Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

What is the workaround?

Comment: You mean _JavaScript_, not Java.  Please note that, though similarly named, they are two unrelated languages.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know accurately but it may work.., if you are using any other script like ajax,Etc it will conflict...,  add like this

```
 var jq = $.noConflict();   
   jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq(window).load(function() {
        jq('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            animationLoop: true,

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried but without any result.

Comment: you should not use $ inside like  .ready(function($) or .load(function($) if you gave jq instad of $....pls check

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the suuport given by you all but congratulate me first (!), the problem is solved. I followed the following steps and the code has started running-

1. I shifted from https to http (less seure platform, can't help)
2. Cancelling one of the two jquery libraries, keepping the latest version
3. and obviously, all that follows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function) Multiple scripts given here, I tested them all, many do work.  :)