# script doesn't work in django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I tried to follow [this](http://astronautradio.com/post/15724356031/infinite-scroll-django) tutorial but for some reason, the JS does nothing in my template.

I copied each step in it, added is an anchor div with an id of “newItems” and included the infinite scroll script as asked.

my template looks like this:

```
<body>
{% for i in "0123456789" %}
{% for j in "0123456789" %}
<li>{{i}} , {{j}}</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<a id="newItems">in here</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(window).bind('scroll', loadOnScroll);
});
// Scroll globals
...
SAME AS IN THE TUTORIAL
...
</script>
</body>
```

my view.py:

```
def debate_archive(request):
    debates = range(1,1000)
    paginator = Paginator(debates, 10)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.is_ajax():
            if request.GET.get('page_number'):
                # Paginate based on the page number in the GET request
                page_number = request.GET.get('page_number');
                try:
                    page_objects = paginator.page(page_number).object_list
                except InvalidPage:
                    return HttpResponseBadRequest(mimetype="json")
                # Serialize the paginated objects
                resp = serialize_debates(page_objects)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), mimetype='json')
    debates = paginator.page(1).object_list
    return render(request, 'polls/example.html', locals())
```

my urls.py:

```
    url(r'^test/$', views.debate_archive, name='home'),
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have some errors in browser console, can you past it here?

Comment: @BearBrown I have no errors

Comment: and what code of the `serialize_debates()` and have you any response from django?

Comment: @BearBrown same code as the tutorial except that the only change is the value of  debates. no bad response from django. it seems like the function does not get any ajax requests

Comment: did you change url in the ajax parameters?

Comment: @BearBrown no. as I understand, is should stay empty

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with templates within another template. I have had the same problem, but couldn't find the solution. Scrips from static are not loaded and inline scripts are not executed if they are positioned in a template of another template.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. In console chrome said that: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`
Here is solution work with me:
you must use jQuery, and $ is not used (this is for compatibility with other libraries)
If you must use `$(document).ready(function(){`, you can actually pass $ into the function call:

```
jQuery(function ($) { ...
```

Find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)