# How do i solve mail code problem while developing theme on wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

It shows that $ is not a function

here is my **function.php** code

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'mail-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mail-script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);


$(document).ready(function() {
        var form = $('#myForm');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Comment: see my error in this link please:https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDW8a.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing "$" with "jQuery" in you js file and test.

Comment: when i try to customize and inspect , it doesn't show error . but when i return to dashboard and click view site it shows error

Comment: see both links please

Comment: Replace all occurrence of "$" in the mail-script.js file

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your jQuery code in this:

```
(function($){

    // jQuery code is in here

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you but its not helping bro please suggest another way . see this link it is showing this again https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDW8a.png

Comment: Make sure you wrap that code inside the code I gave you, so before the error line add this `(function($){` and go to the end of ready function and add this after `})(jQuery);`

Comment: make these changes in the mail-script.js file not in the functions file, this is wrong