# Converting Jquery to javascript to avoid jquery library conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script that works the way I intend it to by appending a set of links within a div's class but unfortunately when I load the jquery library it kills my slider on my Wordpress site's page.

I am trying to rewrite the jquery to javascript so I don't have to rely on the library but am stumped on the syntax.

Here is the jquery that works:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var trail = '#announcements';
        $(".pagination").find('a').attr('href', $(".pagination").find('a').attr('href') + trail);
    });
    </script>
```

And here is what I tried to write in javascript:

```
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var trail = '#announcements';
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination").find('a').attr('href', 
    this.find('a').attr('href') + trail);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This might help: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: However, this very much looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - do you already have another version of jquery on your page that 3.5.1 conflicts with?  Try your original code *without* the `<script src=..3.5.1/jquery.min.js>`  Or look at jquery [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Comment: I mean, i certainly welcome you to move away from jquery, but, this is very much an X/Y problem. If you instead focused on why it's conflicting, that's probably a very easy problem to solve too.

Comment: I would like to use jquery but every time I add a min library link it kills my slider. This is on a wordpress site and I am using the AVADA theme and the Code Block element to put my jquery on the page. @KevinB

Comment: @freedomn-m I was getting an error that said $ is not a function and I learned that in wordpress you have to wrap the code in: jQuery(document).ready(function($){ Insert code here }); I was able to do that and get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was more of an XY problem as pointed out I decided to look into why my jQuery wasn't working and discovered an error that was saying, $ is not a function similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function) post.

So with that in mind, I updated my jquery code and now it works without conflict.

Updated code:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var trail = '#announcements';
        $(".pagination").find('a').attr('href', 
    $(".pagination").find('a').attr('href') + trail);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that a correct translation would look like this:

```
var trail = '#announcements';
var linksInPagination = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pagination a'));

linksInPagination.forEach((link) => {
  link.setAttribute('href', link.getAttribute('href') + trail ); 
});
```

Where are your mistakes?

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination").find('a').attr('href', 
    this.find('a').attr('href') + trail);
```

1. `document.getElementsByClassName("pagination")` does not have `.find()` method.
2. Semanticaly it's defiently not a `<div>` but a Node Colection of `<a>` (so don't call it `div` :))
3. In jQuery you can use `$('p').text('new text')` for more than one `<p>` but in JS you have to loop and call it on elements directly. I'm converting a node collection to array and doing it with forEach method.