# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function when logging checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add string (WooCommerce product tag slug) to URL but I getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

I get inspired by this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2tet/1/)

My JS code is:

```
<script>
     $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox");
     $checkboxes.change(function(){
       window.location.hash = "?product_tag=" + $checkboxes.filter(":checked").map(function(){
           return this.value;   
       }).get().join(",");
       console.log(window.location.hash);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: this question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343739/3739756

Answer (score 1):

You need to add reference to jQuery in your code. Include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network) and it will work.

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
</head>
```